# undefined method `' for #<Conference:0x00000112a617c0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have this very annoying error that is not telling much about where I should look to fix the problem.

```
undefined method `' for #<Conference:0x00000112a617c0>
```

The error is occurring when I want to save a new Conference record via the Rails Admin

The code is the following:

**Conference class:**

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base

  include TheDate

end
```

**module TheDate:**

```
module TheDate
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
     has_many :meeting_dates, as: :dateable, dependent: :destroy
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :meeting_dates, :allow_destroy => true
   end
end
```

**MeetingDate class:**

```
class MeetingDate < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :dateable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :conference, -> { where(:'event_dates.dateable_type' => 'Conference') }, foreign_key:   :dateable_id
  belongs_to :course, -> { where(:'event_dates.dateable_type' => 'Course') }, foreign_key: :dateable_id
  belongs_to :meeting, -> { where(:'event_dates.dateable_type' => 'Meeting') }, foreign_key: :dateable_id

end
```

Would you know what could cause it ? Since there is no method name in the error, I have no idea where to look...

Thanks

Comment: change `where(:'event_dates.dateable_type' => 'Conference')` to `where('event_dates.dateable_type = ?', 'Conference')`

Comment: @bjhaid : I changed it but it didn't help...

Comment: you should change all your `where` to look like what I suggested and it should work

Comment: From which line of which file does this error comes?

Comment: @bjhaid : All the `where`were changed and didn't work

Comment: @MrYoshji: The error is coming from the AR library - method_missing activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb

Comment: You probably have a syntax error, can you create a paste-bin with the content of the file concerned, and the stacktrace ?

Comment: Can you inspect the attributes of the object (quite literal look at conference.attributes.inspect) before you save the object (and ideally repeat this after any before saves that might modify the object)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.where` method like the following:

```
# change this
where(:'event_dates.dateable_type' => 'Conference')

# to the following syntax:
where(event_dates: { dateable_type: 'Conference' })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem.  This post appears to have a fix, although I feel it's a little less than desirable.  There was a change in the way Rails loads in a recent patch, and it messes up the GeneratedAssociationMethods inside the included block.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15253